# When Distributed workers use shared_queue in distributed tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, queue, mutex, distributed, shared

When Distributed workers use shared_queue in distributed tensorflow,
Is the shared_queue works to mutex exclusively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow queue objects, such as [`tf.FIFOQueue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/FIFOQueue), are thread-safe. This applies both to multiple users in a single process, and multiple jobs sharing the queue via `shared_name` in a distributed setting.

Comment: I'm pleased to concern about my question and thanks for replying my question very kindly. It's very helpful to do my project for me.